# Split dictionary into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

The data fetched from API returns a dictionary format stored in a column, as below:

```
{"messaging": true, "newsletters": true, "ranking_coach": true, "sms_reminders": true, "birthday_reminders": true, "merchant_shiftplan": true}
{"messaging": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": false, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": true, "customer_feedback": true, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "reserve_with_google": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": true, "appointment_location_customer": false}
{"messaging": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": false, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": true, "customer_feedback": true, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "reserve_with_google": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": true, "appointment_location_customer": false}
{"messaging": false, "newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "double_opt_in_required": false}
{"messaging": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": false, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": true, "customer_feedback": true, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "reserve_with_google": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": true, "appointment_location_customer": false}
{"square": false, "insights": true, "api_token": false, "messaging": true, "wait_list": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": true, "pdf_prefill": false, "free_product": false, "website_duda": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": true, "contact_widget": false, "online_booking": true, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "shared_customers": false, "customer_feedback": true, "external_services": false, "birthday_reminders": true, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "net_promoter_score": false, "new_booking_widget": true, "reserve_with_google": false, "file_download_widget": false, "automated_newsletters": true, "double_opt_in_required": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": false, "new_closingtime_background": false, "gdpr_marketing_opt_in_modal": false, "appointment_location_customer": false, "facebook_instagram_integration": false, "new_full_screen_booking_widget": true, "merchant_logo_on_customer_email": true, "show_all_branch_option_on_insights": false, "participating_account_notifications": false, "show_newsletter_non_subscriber_selection": false}
{"reporting": true, "newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "customer_feedback": true, "reserve_with_google": true, "new_closingtime_background": true, "merchant_logo_on_customer_email": true}
{"messaging": false, "yext_sync": false, "marketplace": false, "newsletters": false, "ranking_coach": false, "sms_reminders": false, "sms_newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": true, "customer_feedback": true, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_dashboard": true, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "reserve_with_google": false, "sms_customer_confirmation": false, "individual_email_from_name": true, "appointment_location_customer": false}
{"messaging": false, "newsletters": false, "merchant_payment": false, "birthday_reminders": false, "merchant_shiftplan": false, "double_opt_in_required": false, "new_closingtime_background": true, "facebook_instagram_integration": true, "show_all_branch_option_on_insights": true, "show_newsletter_non_subscriber_selection": false}
{"sms_reminders": true, "customer_feedback": true, "merchant_dashboard": true, "reserve_with_google": false, "show_all_branch_option_on_insights": true}
```

An interesting point to note is that not all of the rows have the same features.
For instance, row#1 to row#5 start with messaging, row #6 start with square, row #7 start with reporting.

I would like to split this one column into multiple columns, where each column has only 1 feature.

Expected Output:

```
No. messaging   newsletter    ranking_coach   sms_reminders
1     true        true            true             true
2     false       null            null             null
3     false       null            null             null
..
6     null        null            null             null
```

Comment: Is there a set list of features/columns or do you want it to be dynamic?

Comment: as the company may look to increase its features in the future, dynamic would be better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use json functionality in postgresql:

```
select
    Jsoncol ->> 'messaging' messaging,
    Jsoncol ->> 'newsletters' newsletters,
    Jsoncol ->> 'ranking_coach' ranking_coach,
    Jsoncol ->> 'sms_reminders' sms_reminders
from tablename
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7de2e9c0aa24decad676d1de990aa451)*

Comment: Invalid operation: operator does not exist: character varying ->> "unknown";

Comment: @Luc which version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.29551